# Cannot select dependency based on platform in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I am learning Bazel and trying to build some third-party libraries. I sometimes use my mac and sometimes I use my linux computer. Hence, when I build `opencv` I want to use different `linkopts` depending on platform.

From what I have read one should use `select` and `@platforms`. This is what I have, but when I build on my Linux machine I get:

```
ERROR: Target //thirdparty/opencv:opencv is incompatible and cannot be built, but was explicitly requested.
Dependency chain:
    //thirdparty/opencv:opencv (442d8d)
    //thirdparty/opencv:opencv_deps (442d8d)   <-- target platform (@local_config_platform//:host) didn't satisfy constraint @platforms//os:osx
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.284s
```

Seems like it is not respecting the selection?

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_library")
load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

cc_library(
    name = "opencv_deps",
    linkopts = select({
        "@platforms//os:macos": [
        "-ldl", 
        "-lz", 
        "-lpthread",
        "-lavutil",
        "-lavformat", 
        "-lavcodec", 
        "-lswscale", 
        "-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ffmpeg/lib", 
        "-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.6/lib", 
        "-framework Cocoa",
        "-framework Accelerate",
        ],
        "@platforms//os:linux": [
            "-ldl",
            "-lz",
            "-lpthread"
        ],
    }),
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:macos",
        "@platforms//os:linux"
    ],
)

cmake(
    name = "opencv",
    build_args = [
        "-j3",
    ],
    cache_entries = {
        "OPENCV_FORCE_3RDPARTY_BUILD": "ON",
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_TESTS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_PERF_TESTS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_apps": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_calib3d": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_core": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_dnn": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_features2d": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_flann": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_gapi": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_highgui": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_imgcodecs": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_imgproc": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_js": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_ml": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_objdetect": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_photo": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_stitching": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_ts": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_video": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_videoio": "ON",
        "BUILD_opencv_world": "ON",
        "BUILD_IPP_IW": "ON",
        "WITH_ADE": "OFF",
        "WITH_CAROTENE": "OFF",
        "WITH_IPP": "OFF",
        "WITH_ITT": "ON",
        "WITH_OPENEXR": "OFF",
        "WITH_JASPER": "OFF",
        "WITH_JPEG": "OFF",
        "WITH_OPENJPEG": "ON",
        "WITH_TIFF": "OFF",
        "WITH_WEBP": "ON",
        "WITH_QUIRC": "ON",
        "WITH_GTK": "OFF",
        "WITH_OPENBLAS": "ON",
        "WITH_OPENCL": "OFF",
    },
    env = {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "RelWithDebInfo",
        "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL": "16",
    },
    lib_source = "@opencv//:opencv_all",
    out_include_dir = "include/opencv4",
    out_static_libs = [
        "libopencv_world.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/libittnotify.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibopenjp2.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibwebp.a",
        "opencv4/3rdparty/liblibpng.a",
    ],
    targets = [
        "install",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":opencv_deps"]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misuse the `target_compatible_with` attribute. It cannot have multiple values, i.e. cannot be `macos` and `linux` at the same time. Remove the `target_compatible_with` attribute and it should work then.

From [the documentation](https://bazel.build/reference/be/common-definitions#common.target_compatible_with):

> target_compatible_with: List of labels; default is [] A list of constraint_values that must be present in the target platform for this target to be considered compatible. This is in addition to any constraints already set by the rule type. If the target platform does not satisfy all listed constraints then the target is considered incompatible.